# how to trim last spaces in end of the statement by using xslt

Tags: xslt-1.0

how  to  trim last spaces in my sentence by using version-1.0

**note : it should not effect the space in between words in my sentence.(has to trim space in  end of the statement)**

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the code of the [`trim`](http://fxsl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/fxsl/fxsl-xslt2/f/trim.xsl?revision=1.1&view=markup) function/template of [FXSL](http://fxsl.sf.net)**.

**Here is an example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:import href="trim.xsl"/>

  <!-- to be applied on trim.xml -->

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    '<xsl:call-template name="trim">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="string(/*)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>'
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the XML document below**:

```
<someText>

   This is    some text   

</someText>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
'This is    some text'
```